# Pagination with REST API

Tags: angular, rest, pagination

I have to get data using REST API and consume it in an Angular 2 table.

So I'm wondering which is the best solution:

1. Dealing with pagination, sort and filter in API side. So API will return only data to show in current page. It will be many calls to API using this method since each action will provoque API call.
2. API returns all data, and pagination/filter/sort  will be managed using Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is solution 1), so you can avoid extracting all data from the database too. This will save bandwidth, time and memory on the client. The approach 2) will work if you are dealing with small ( and surely not growing ) datasets, in this case have the filtering/paging server side would be an over-design.